# apache nutch 2.2.1 Error in execution

Tags: nutch

I'm trying to execute nutch 2.2.1 from windows 8 on my local computervia cygdrive.
I followed the configuration instruction and this is the command I execute in folder src:

**./bin/crawl urls/ testCrawl/  //127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ 1**

the parameters according to:
 crawl

The solr link is working on my local machine, and the folders urls & testCrawl exists.

I got error message and I have no idea what should I do:

he-nutch-2.2.1/src
$ ./bin/crawl urls/ testCrawl/ //127.0.0.1:8181/solr/ 1

**cygpath: can't convert empty path**

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob**

I saw in other forum to run the commands from $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/ but I don't have the runtime folder at all.. I saw that in 2.2.1 it was removed and the instruction is to exec it form the nutch home folder

Anyone know what I need to do to make it work?? maybe change something in the configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using OSX, but I had that same error about `Could not find or load main class ...InjectorJob`, and I believe that it is the result of a dirty source directory, in my case, I had checked it out via Git, and changed branches a few times, as I was trying out various features. So, you've been running `ant` or `ant runtime` to rebuild the runtime/deploy directory, but to solve this, I had to run:

`ant clean`

Which deletes this compiled output, and recompiles it properly. After this point, the crawl command runs properly.